# Looping through all the inputs and creating distinct output files

Tags: file, unix, cygwin

I am using *cygwin* on *Windows 7*. I have a folder with about 1200 files of the same type(There are no sub-directories). I am trying to go through the folder and perform a certain action(it's bioinformatic alignment) on each file. Here is the code that I am using:

`$ for file in Project/genomes_0208/*;
 do ./bowtie-build $file ../bowtie-0.12.7/indexes/abc;
 done`

`./bowtie` - build is the operation that I want to perform. Now, this does complete the operation for all the files in the folder,but it keeps writing the ouput in the same file **abc** in this case.

So in the end I have only 1 file with the latest output. How can I create 1200 different files , one for each of the input? It doesn't matter what I name the output files, it could be anything, as long as they are obviously different.

Hope I explained the problem successfully, I'd appreciate any help with this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
./bowtie-build $file "${file}.out"
```

If your files had unique names to begin with this should also produce unique output files.

Comment: I'll check this as soon as I get back on my comp.

Comment: @dawnoflife You might want to tweak the path but the general idea is to include `${file}` somewhere to ensure uniqueness.

Comment: it gives me "could not open the <output file name> file" error.

Comment: @dawnoflife Perhaps it lacks permissions ?

Comment: Probably not, when I give the output file name as just "abc"...it works(1200 times).  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @dawnoflife Check to make sure you're using the same path. I omitted your path in the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I give the entire path.

Comment: Let me clarify just so I am not misleading, the program runs for 1200 times, but all the tries give the message "could not open file for writing"

Comment: I don't know if this information might help, but the file names are of the form "NC_XXXXXX" where "XXXXXX" are just numbers 0-9. could be repeated but the file names are unique.

Comment: Strange, I ran it again and now it shows the message "Please make sure the directory exists and that permissions allow writing by bowtie."The directory definitely exists and as far as permssions go, it's able to write with my old code so it should be fine, correct?

Comment: @dawnoflife Echo the path as passed to the program. Then try to manually touch a file there.

Comment: @dawnoflife So what was the catch ?

Comment: I think there was a problem with the folder I was trying to save the data. I tried saving the output in the same folder as the inputs, and it works though now I have about 10,000 files in that folder lol. That's an easy fixm thanks for the help! :-)