# Looping through all the inputs in a directory and creating output directories with the input name

Tags: bash, loops

I have a directory with 10 different files and I need to run the same command over all the files, but save the results in separate directories that are unique with my input file names as the results directories name. I understand that my question is similar to [Looping through all the inputs and creating distinct output files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521862/looping-through-all-the-inputs-and-creating-distinct-output-files) and so i tried the following code:

```
cd /user/test

for i in *.txt
do 
   fastqc $i -o {$i}.out
done
```

I get an  error :

```
Specified output directory '{1.txt}.out' does not exist
Specified output directory '{2.txt}.out' does not exist
```

I was wondering what might be the problem, as it would be helpful while creating pipelines and workflows.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use `find` which is useful if your files are in nested directories:

```
find /user/test -name '*.txt' -exec fastqc "{}" -o "{}.out" \;
```

`find` will execute the command specified after `-exec` for all the .txt files it has found in /user/test (the search is recursive).

Answer (score 2):

You have `{` and `}` outside, you need to use:

```
cd /user/test    
for i in *.txt; do
   fastqc "$i" -o "${i}.out"
done
```

OR just:

```
for i in *.txt; do
   fastqc "$i" -o "$i.out"
done
```

Since DOT is not considered part of the variable name.